# How to replace percent (%) character

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, sql-update

How to update a row to replace percent character.

```
UPDATE MPOLITICAS SET NOM_POLITICA =  REPLACE(NOM_POLITICA, '%' , 'PERCENT ');
```

The row content is `NG DEBT 100% - 2014`

but should be `NG DEBT 100 PERCENT - 2014`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace function should work fine for this:

```
UPDATE MPOLITICAS SET NOM_POLITICA =  REPLACE(NOM_POLITICA, '%' , ' PERCENT');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cc2c4/1

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that works for select statement but no in a replace. Note  the percent character is closed to a number.

Comment: The Percent's proximity to a number won't affect the replace at all. The replace only cares about the characters that it's searching for. Also, if you can use the function in a SELECT statement, you can generally use it in an UPDATE statement as well. Good luck! :)

Comment: I am ashamed of my. I didn't commit;  Sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your locale (NLS settings) have ASCII 37 as the % character:

```
UPDATE MPOLITICAS SET NOM_POLITICA =  REPLACE(NOM_POLITICA, CHR(37) , ' ');
```

Comment: I have tried this solution, but didn't work. Please note the percent character is closed to a number.

Answer (score -1):

You can use TRANSLATE() http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/translate.php

```
UPDATE MPOLITICAS SET NOM_POLITICA = translate(NOM_POLITICA, '%', '')
-> NG DEBT 100 - 2014
```

Or Replace()

```
UPDATE MPOLITICAS SET NOM_POLITICA = Replace(NOM_POLITICA, '%', ' percent')
-> NG DEBT 100 percent - 2014
```

Comment: I'm getting "ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION database.TRANSLATE does not exist"